# SQL - SELECT with JOINED Table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a selection from the user tabel. For each user i would like to sum the Timediff for all posts in `tblregtime` for current user for given date parameters.

Problem is that i need to get information even if there is no registration done at the given date for current user. If no registration i need output that  current user has `TotalDiff=0`. My current SQL doesn't work  in this way. It will just give the `fname`,`lname` and `TotalDiff` if there is a post in `tblregtime`

---

sql:

```
 select  u.fname,u.lname, sum(cast(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(r.edate,r.sdate)) AS UNSIGNED)-r.break_time) as TotalDiff

from tbluser u 

RIGHT OUTER JOIN tblregtime r on r.userid=u.id where r.projectid=21
and  year(r.sdate)=2013 and month(r.sdate)=10 and day(r.sdate)=7
```

Comment: First please make sure all your fields have the tablename or alias. Who can tell what table they belong to. You should never ever write any sql where it is unclear where the fields came from.

Comment: You have sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to keep everything in `tbluser`, then you want a `left join` instead of a `right join`.  However, you also need to move the `where` conditions into the `on` clause.  Otherwise, when there is no match, the comparisons will fail (because the `r.` values will be `NULL`):

```
select u.fname,u.lname,
       sum(cast(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(r.edate,r.sdate)) AS UNSIGNED)-r.break_time) as TotalDiff
from tbluser u LEFT JOIN
     tblregtime r
     on r.userid = u.id and
        r.projectid = 21 and
        year(r.sdate) = 2013 and month(r.sdate) = 10 and day(r.sdate) = 7;
```

I would also recommend that you change the final date comparison to something like:

```
r.sdate = '2013-10-07'
```

This form would allow the use of an index on `r.sdate`.  As you have written it, the SQL engine (at least the SQL engines I am familiar with) would not be smart enough to use the index.

Comment: This solved my problem when moving the where conditions to the on clause. My final code:  `select u.fname,u.lname,
       sum(cast(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(r.edate,r.sdate)) AS UNSIGNED)-r.break_time) as TotalDiff
from tbluser u LEFT JOIN
     tblregtime r
     on (r.userid = u.id and
        r.projectid = 21 and
        date(sdate)='2013-10-01'
        )
        
INNER JOIN tblgroup_users gU ON gU.userID = u.id 
INNER JOIN tblgroup_project gB on gB.tblGroupID=gU.tblGroupID 


where gB.tblprojectID=21
AND (gU.status=0 OR gU.status=2) 
group by r.userid

     order by u.fname ASC,u.lname ASC`